# No result result returned with query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to execute the following query to return the first and last dates in a month but the query doesn't return any values.

```
DECLARE @today AS DATETIME 
SET @today= CAST('2012-08-24' AS DATETIME)

--First day of month

SELECT DATEADD(dd, -DAY(@today) + 1, @today)
UNION
--Last day of month

SELECT DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(mm, 1, @today)), DATEADD(mm, 1, @today))
```

However when executing it I get the following result:

```
10:36:13  [DECLARE - 1 row(s), 0.005 secs]  Command processed
... 1 statement(s) executed, 1 row(s) affected, exec/fetch time: 0.005/0.000 sec  [1 successful, 0 warnings, 0 errors]
```

I would like to see the result of the query and not just only that the command has been processed. How to fix this? When using it without declaring variables like this:

```
--First
SELECT DATEADD(dd, -DAY(CAST('2012-08-24' AS DATETIME)) + 1, CAST('2012-08-24' AS DATETIME))
UNION
--Last day of month
SELECT DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(mm, 1, CAST('2012-08-24' AS DATETIME))), DATEADD(mm, 1, CAST('2012-08-24' AS DATETIME)))
```

It returns the intended result:

```
2012-08-01 00:00:00
2012-08-31 00:00:00
```

How to fix this?

Comment: How are you executing it?

Comment: Try putting `SET NOCOUNT ON;` at the start of your statement.

Comment: It's working fine. both of your SQL query returns same result.

Comment: Well not for me. I'm executing it using DbVisualizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the above mentioned `SET NOCOUNT ON;` at the end of the query like this:

```
DECLARE @today AS DATETIME 
SET @today= CAST('2012-08-24' AS DATETIME)

--First day of month

SELECT DATEADD(dd, -DAY(@today) + 1, @today)
UNION
--Last day of month

SELECT DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(mm, 1, @today)), DATEADD(mm, 1, @today))
SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

Worked for me and I then returned the following intended result:

```
2012-08-01 00:00:00
2012-08-31 00:00:00
```

However I don't know why this statement is needed. Any idea why?

Comment: certain operations, although they do not return a result set, still return information from the server, for example if you perform a `DELETE` the number of rows deleted are returned. I assume that you are using the free version of DBVisualizer which does not support multiple statements, since the operation `SET @Today = CAST(...` is returning a message to DBVisualiser that 1 row was affected by the `SET` operation, this is considered your one allowed statement.

Comment: For more information read about NOCOUNT on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx